# Disabling Nametags Vanilla

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen a vanilla map where they hid name tags for PVP. How did they accomplish this? I want completely hidden name tags, or if it's possible to remove them for other teams?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `scoreboard` command like this:

```
/scoreboard teams option <team> nametagVisibility hideForOtherTeams
```

This will hide the nametags for players on the team from other teams (and players not on a team).

Answer (score 0):

If you use PE there is a setting which disables it for an individual player. Under Video Settings. It might also be on other versions.

Comment: It would be prefer if you add some image for the answer.